# ¿Cómo añadir una libreria desde npm o yarn?

Tags: librería

En la pagina oficial se menciona que para instalar la versión en Sass se puede utilizar "npm" o también "yarn" el problema es que nosé donde tengo que poner las lineas de codigo de instalación de la libreria que da la pagina, ya intente poniendo estas lineas de codigo al principio del archivo sass y también escribiendo la linea donde se importa la libreria pero no funciona, ¿Cómo le hago?

Comment: Son sistemas de gestión de paquetes para Node.js. Para poder trabajar con ellas, debes tener instalado previamente NodeJs, Si ya lo tienes instalado puedes verificar con el comando `node -v`. este ira en la consola de windows (de linux o de git si lo usas).